# I want to vlookup dataframe.If value is present in another df ,keep same value,otherwise put #N/A in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, merge

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Car':['Jeep', 'Maruti Suzuki', 'Audi','Kia'],
        'order':[10,15,2,5]}
        # Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
print (df)
output:
             Car  order
0           Jeep     10
1  Maruti Suzuki     15
2           Audi      2
3            Kia      5
```

```
data = {'Car':['Jeep', 'Maruti Suzuki','Kia'],
        'City':['M','P',"D"]
        }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
print (df2)
            Car City
0           Jeep    M
1  Maruti Suzuki    P
2            Kia    D
```

Required output

```
           Car          Available     order
0           Jeep           Jeep     10
1  Maruti Suzuki  Maruti Suzuki     15
2           Audi           #N/A      2
3            Kia            Kia      5
```

I want to vlookup.If df['Car'] is present in df2,Keep as the same value.and if not present in df2,add #N/A in df[' Available'].

Required output

```
             Car      Available  order
0           Jeep           Jeep     10
1  Maruti Suzuki  Maruti Suzuki     15
2           Audi           #N/A      2
3            Kia            Kia      5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `merge` with `indicator` parameter:

```
out = pd.merge(df, df2['Car'], on='Car', how='left', indicator=True)
out['Available'] = np.where(out['_merge'] == 'both', out['Car'], '#N/A')
# out = out.drop(columns='_merge')
```

```
>>> out[['Car', 'Available', 'order']]
             Car      Available  order
0           Jeep           Jeep     10
1  Maruti Suzuki  Maruti Suzuki     15
2           Audi           #N/A      2
3            Kia            Kia      5
```

Comment: Thanks.But i want to add new column  with car data.and if data is not available  df2 then add #N/A

Comment: @San. I updated my answer. It should be good now.

Comment: np.where works only if two dataframe are same in length.what if i have different length of df

Comment: `out` has always the length of `df` because you merge `left`. I should replace `df['Car']` by `out['Car']`

Comment: @San, Do you have time to try the code?

Comment: Hi Corralian,This code works for me.Thank u